# Class being over written by other class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is a simple CSS issue. I have site that has the following problem:

```
#main-content ol {
list-style-type: decimal;
padding-left: 25px;}                                  /* abc.css (line 140) */

#contentWrapper p, #contentWrapper ul, #contentWrapper ol, #lmBlurbsArchive {
color: #666666;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 0;}                                       /* abc.css (line 69) */

/* Code below being striped out/ over written by other class above */
ol.upper-roman {
list-style-type: upper-roman;
```

Answer (score 3):

`#main-content ol.upper-roman` should be specific enough to "win".

So, in your CSS, change `ol.upper-roman` to the above selector.

Give these a read:

- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 3):

A selector using an ID has a higher value than a selector using just a class, so `#main-content ol` is given preference over `ol.upper-roman`.

You´d have to use `#main-content ol.upper-roman` to overwrite the settings on line 140.